# Is there any spec on BookmarkDAV?

Tags: icloud, webdav, caldav, carddav

Tinkering with iCloud, I found out that it is using some tweaked form of WebDAV to store and sync calendars, contacts and bookmarks. I got some specs on CalDAV and CardDAV searching in Google, but for bookmarks Apple seems to have developed its own *BookmarkDAV* protocol. Is there any documentation on this protocol available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, BookmarkDAV is no standard whatsoever.

Comment: Why did this get a down vote? (Unfortunately) this is the right answer :-> BookmarkDAV is neither spec'ed nor documented.